# Why is it not possible to map BehaviorSubject to another BehaviorSubject

Tags: android, mvvm, rx-java2

At least in mobile apps `BehaviorSubject` is used frequently, to model a property - it has a current value, which can be queried any time, and be observed.

Sometimes it's wanted to just transform a `BehaviorSubject` without subscribing to it. E.g. if there's class, that acts as an intermediate layer between several transformed `BehaviorSubject` and potential subscribers.

The issue I have encountered here, at least with RxJava2, is that applying operators on `BehaviorSubject` returns always `Observable`. So my intermediate layer can't offer anymore an api of `BehaviorSubject`.

A possible solution is to create new `BehaviorSubject`s and subscribe them to the original `BehaviorSubject` but this seems a bad idea overall, maybe I don't want to subscribe at this moment but only on demand, i.e. when the users of my intermediate layer actually needs these subjects?

In my case the context is an Android app with MVVM pattern, where the view model exposes `BehaviorSubject` to the views, which are for the most part derived from another `BehaviorSubject`s in the app. I currently went with subscribing in the view model, but I would like to improve this since the view model isn't really the consumer and shouldn't be subscribing to anything - the subjects should be activated when the view actually needs something from them.

And no I can't use only `Observable` in the view model as there are unit tests and some other calls that check for the value at a point, which can't be done using only `Observable`.

My main question is why is it not possible to simply be able to transform `BehaviorSubject` into another `BehaviorSubject`. A nice to have also, what is the recommended way to work with `BehaviorSubject` in the described context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would not compose properly, operators are final methods to avoid method dispatch problems. Plus, you'd create multiple entry points for and end consumer and possibly violate the Observable contract if you's onNext the transformed subject while also onNext the original subject.

But you can have multiple subjects merged together, each driven by its own respective events and the end consumers would receive events properly.

> And no I can't use only Observable in the view model as there are unit tests and some other calls that check for the value at a point, which can't be done using only Observable.

Have you tried `blockingFirst()` to get the current value from a chain that starts from those original `BehaviorSubject`?

Otherwise, your design is unclear to me as it is too much focused on subjects other than being a single originator of some events.

Comment: Thanks. It's clearer now. I think `blockingFirst` isn't an alternative in some cases, e.g. to replace a behavior subject that was initialized with a default value... also wouldn't this cause a possible source observable to activate (while blocking the current thread)?

Comment: Also: In iOS, for example, there's reactive cocoa and a class called `Property` and applying operators to properties simply return another `Property` (property is essentially an observable with a "value" field, similar to `BehaviorSubject`). I'm porting the business logic components to Android... and I just wonder why constructs like this are available there and not here (this is not a criticism, I have no idea about the internals).